# Multiple directives and ng-transclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I'm having a problem using ng-transclude on an element of multiple directives.

I have two directives where one instantiates the other:

```
//Basic first directive, checks if the second should be instantiated
app.directive('configModal', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {
            manage: '=manage',
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
            //used to instantiate the second directive which is 'C' restricted
            $element.addClass('widget-config-managed');
            $compile($element);
            };
        }
    };
}]);

//Second directive, has two wrap the content of the element by transclusion
app.directive('configManaged', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        template: '<div ng-transclude>Some more content</div>',
        transclude: true,
        compile: function(element){
            console.log('compile from managed');
        }
    };
}]);
```

The HTML looks like so:

```
<div class="widget-config-modal">
<div>
    Just some div.
</div>
```

The problem is that the div's orignial content:

```
    <div>
        Just some div.
    </div>
```

is not transcluded but completely overwritten by the template.

How can the transclusion be fixed?

Comment: Try `replace: false` for your configManaged directive.

Comment: Have you tried to use 'replace: false' within your 'configManaged' directive configuration? also have a look at this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2235

Comment: I tried 'replace: false' and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your directive is functional. You cannot prefix the directive with a `widget-`. If you want you can prefix it with `x-` or `data-`

So `<div class="widget-config-modal">` dont work.

Instead you can do as below:

```
<div class="config-modal">
<!-- OR -->
<div class="data-config-modal">
<!-- OR -->
<div class="x-config-modal">
```

Comment: The directives seem to run fine with the 'widget-' prefix, the problem is more specific with the transclusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `ng-transclude` in the first directive to include the current inner node `<div> Just some div. </div>`. In the second directive, there is no need for `ng-transclude`.

In *configModal*:

```
transclude: true,
template: '<div><div ng-transclude></div><div class="config-managed"></div></div>'
```

In *configManaged*:

```
template: '<div>Some more content</div>'
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6L7jA/6/)**</kbd>